# How set buttons below list made of textviews?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, textview

I am making an application to print on screen list of beacons with their uuid, major and minor values. Each value is strored as a textview in xml file. This works fine, but I want also to set below this whole list with beacons a table row with four buttons. But when I am adding a table row in my xml file, my table with buttons keeps showing in each position on my list.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEvbC.jpg

So my question is how to set table of buttons below list made of textviews?

**My xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_uuid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_major"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_minor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5cl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newscl"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="News"
            android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loccl"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="---"
            android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leccl"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="----"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clacl"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="---"
            android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

**List adapter**

```
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<IBeacon> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<IBeacon>();
        mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(IBeacon device) {
        if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public IBeacon getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            viewHolder.deviceUUID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_uuid);
            viewHolder.deviceMajor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_major);
            viewHolder.deviceMinor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_minor);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        IBeacon device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        final String deviceName = "Kontakt";
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
       //viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        viewHolder.deviceUUID.setText(device.getUuid());
        viewHolder.deviceMajor.setText(device.getMajor());
        viewHolder.deviceMinor.setText(device.getMinor());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new row, you are using the xml that contain the button, you should separe your row design, for example.

rowBeacon.xml (use this in your adapter)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_uuid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_major"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_minor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your activity (setContentView) use something like this:

activity.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/popup_divider"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5cl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/newscl"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="News"
                android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loccl"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="---"
                android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/leccl"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="----"
                android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clacl"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="---"
                android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>
```

In your class (yourClass.java)

```
ListView listData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listData);
...Build your adapter...

listData.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

I hope help you.

Comment: No, my app is stopping when I'm doing this.

Comment: Can you post the exception or in what part is stoping?

Comment: This line is stopping the app:
ListView listData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listData);

Comment: Do your class extends from Activity or what is extending?, in setContenView are you using the XML that had the ListView?

Comment: Yes, in setContenView I am using the XML that had the ListView. My class extends ListActivity

Comment: If you create the ListView in the XML, change your extends to AppCompatActivity or Activity (is your choice), instead ListActivity.

Comment: It should be something like this:
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
And in java:
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `TableRow` is in the layout that you are using for each item. You have to place your `TableRow` below the `ListView`, not in the `ListView` items' layout.

Comment: But I don't define any listview, so should I add this somehow in java code or change my xml file?

Comment: Are you using a ListFragment?

Comment: No, I changed my question to give you extended view on how my list works.

Comment: And this is my only xml in my app, I'm not setting a layout in onCreate method

Comment: I don't understand, where is the ListView coming from? Are you creating it programmatically?

Comment: This is an arraylist and I am adding my devices into it with mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(iBeacon);

Comment: Still, how do you display your list. You add items to the adapter, fine, but, the adapter must be attached to some kind of list.